# Testing a nominal variable against a non-continuous variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, discrete-data, categorical-data

I have a nominal IV (Group 1, 2, 3) and all of the participants (n=70) performed a 7 question quiz. I want to test the Group number against the number of correct answers (i.e. 8 possible values). The data is approximately normally distributed, *except* a spike on 7/7 correct.

There is an obvious difference by visual inspection, but I'd like to quantify this, and I am stumped.

I gather ANOVA is not the right approach as the data is not continuous. Is a Kruskal-Wallis test appropriate for this?

Comment: Are you trying to compare population means in particular or is the hypothesis more general?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, that's all it is. The groups have received different treatments, and H0 is that there is no effect.

Comment: I am confused. I was asking "is it A or B" and your answer is "yes"?

Comment: @Glen_b  My bad! The primary point of interest is indeed the difference between population means.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dependent variable is a count, I would look at count regression models.

Since you have a lot of 7's (all correct) then I might transpose it into a "number wrong" and use zero-inflated negative binomial regression.